# How the workflow control "type" is related to .CS class file?

Tags: c#, .net, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I have a workflow (flowchart) application developed in .Net.
The workflow has many control; few control type is waiting and few control type is sendemail.
I have a "wait" class and "email class" in the workflow project.
The "wait" class (wait.cs) has an execute method.

```
protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
{
  //Database activity is performed here.
}
```

I would like to know, how this execute method is getting called?

As per fundamental, this should be called from an object. However, are there different ways of calling this method?

I'm sure that, the execute method is getting called. But, I am unable to find how, and from where?

Answer (score 0):

[WorkflowInvoker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activities.workflowinvoker?view=netframework-4.8) and [WorkflowApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activities.workflowapplication?view=netframework-4.8) are responsible to invoke or to provide a hosting environment for your workflow definitions and calls the corresponding execute method. You can find more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/using-workflowinvoker-and-workflowapplication) with example.